# Perl - Substitute after nth delimiter

Tags: bash, perl, awk, delimiter, substitution

i would like some help with a substitution i want to do on the lines of a file that look like this :

```
aoipp;dadada.12312;ss;1245454;Xiop;12.12;45.3;47.897;31.5;
asdfafd;14355.54664;peasd;125.1;900.2;76.897;67.456;asdfdf;
perio;777.2;ipoes;900.34;2;1980.45;870.98;67.67;
```

I want to replace every `.` with `,` but only after the fifth occurrence of the delimiter `;`. Everything else needs to remain unchanged. So the desired output file would look like this :

```
aoipp;dadada.12312;ss;1245454;Xiop;12,12;45,3;47,897;31,5;
asdfafd;14355.54664;peasd;125.1;900.2;76,897;67,456;asdfdf;
perio;777.2;ipoes;900.34;2;1980,45;870,98;67,67;
```

I m interested in doing this primarily in perl so i can incorporate it to a larger program, but any solutions in bash / awk are welcome as well. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I dont know why people keep downvoting me. All the answers below reached the desired result, but i can only accept one.

Comment: Probably because you've not made any attempt to solve the problem yourself.

Comment: Fair enough. I dont know as much regex as required to handle this. Next time i ll post some of my failed attempts when i start a question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This awk one-liner should work for you:

```
awk -F';' -v OFS=";" '{for(i=6;i<=NF;i++)gsub("[.]",",",$i)}7' file
```

It starts from the 6th field (`;` separated), for each field replace all `.` by `,`.

Test with your data:

```
kent$  cat f
aoipp;dadada.12312;ss;1245454;Xiop;12.12;45.3;47.897;31.5;
asdfafd;14355.54664;peasd;125.1;900.2;76.897;67.456;asdfdf;
perio;777.2;ipoes;900.34;2;1980.45;870.98;67.67;

kent$  awk -F';' -v OFS=";" '{for(i=6;i<=NF;i++)gsub("[.]",",",$i)}7' f
aoipp;dadada.12312;ss;1245454;Xiop;12,12;45,3;47,897;31,5;
asdfafd;14355.54664;peasd;125.1;900.2;76,897;67,456;asdfdf;
perio;777.2;ipoes;900.34;2;1980,45;870,98;67,67;
```

Comment: Thank you very much. That '7' in the end is slightly confusing, but what you suggested works.

Comment: @onlyf it does just printing,

Comment: The first arg for awks *sub() functions is a regexp, not a string, so use regexp delimiters `/.../` not string delimiters `"..."` as the latter makes your code more complicated as awk has to convert the string to a regexp before using it.

Answer (score 3):

I used an array slice `@fields[ 5 .. $#fields ]` to access only the elements to be changed.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;

my @input = qw( aoipp;dadada.12312;ss;1245454;Xiop;12.12;45.3;47.897;31.5;
                asdfafd;14355.54664;peasd;125.1;900.2;76.897;67.456;asdfdf;
                perio;777.2;ipoes;900.34;2;1980.45;870.98;67.67;
              );

my @expected = qw( aoipp;dadada.12312;ss;1245454;Xiop;12,12;45,3;47,897;31,5;
                   asdfafd;14355.54664;peasd;125.1;900.2;76,897;67,456;asdfdf;
                   perio;777.2;ipoes;900.34;2;1980,45;870,98;67,67;
                 );

sub process {
    my (@input) = @_;
    my @output;
    for my $line (@input) {
        my @fields = split /;/, $line;
        s/\./,/ for @fields[ 5 .. $#fields ];
        push @output, join ';', @fields, q();
    }
    return \@output
}

use Test::More tests => 1;
is_deeply(process(@input), \@expected);
```

Answer (score 3):

```
while (my $line = <DATA>) {
    if ($line =~ /^(?:[^;]*;){5}/) {
        substr($line, $+[0]) =~ y/./,/;
    }
    print $line;
}
__DATA__
aoipp;dadada.12312;ss;1245454;Xiop;12.12;45.3;47.897;31.5;
asdfafd;14355.54664;peasd;125.1;900.2;76.897;67.456;asdfdf;
perio;777.2;ipoes;900.34;2;1980.45;870.98;67.67;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
perl -pe 's/(.*?;){6}\K(.*)/$2 =~ s!\.!,!rg /ge'
```

1. Skip everything until the 6th `;`  (`(.*?;){6}\K`),
2. and aply the substitution . , to rest of the line (`$2 =~ s!\.!,!rg`)

Answer (score 0):

```
  # this should do your work
  sed -i 's/;/,/6g' filename

  cat filename
  aoipp;dadada.12312;ss;1245454;Xiop;12.12,45.3,47.897,31.5,
  asdfafd;14355.54664;peasd;125.1;900.2;76.897,67.456,asdfdf,
  perio;777.2;ipoes;900.34;2;1980.45,870.98,67.67,
```

Comment: I dont need to replace ';'s (semicolons)  i need to replace '.' (full stop) with ',' (comma) after the fifth occurence of ';'.